# load contacts from telegram to C#

Tags: c#

I am using language programming C# and I am making a program that is using Telegram API called TLSharp and I wanna know can I load My contacts from Telegram So I used these codes that I found in stackoverflow but something went wrong

```
 private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            client = new TelegramClient(****, "****");
            await client.ConnectAsync();
            button2.BackColor = Color.Green;
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Text = "Connected";
        }
        catch
        {
            button2.BackColor = Color.Red;
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Text = "Disconnected";
        }
    }
    string hash;
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            hash = await client.SendCodeRequestAsync(textBox1.Text);
            panel1.Hide();
            panel2.Show();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error");
        }
    }

    private async void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await client.GetContactsAsync();

            //find recipient in contacts
            var user = result.users.lists.Where(x=>x.GetType()==typeof(TLUser)).Cast<TLUser>();

            foreach (var item in user.username)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

> But the problem is here , the list-box shows something which isn't Username and I don't know what is it and the list-box shall show my username of my contacts; It shows only my username like this @username

Comment: "shows something which isn't Username and I don't know what is it"  -- care to show *us* what it is?  How else could we possibly hope to help you?

Comment: "So I used these codes but something went wrong" what specifically went wrong?

Comment: When I saw My listbox I saw the word @username

Comment: I mean my user id

Comment: But I need My Contacts names

Comment: From the [TLSharp home](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp): "
Ask your question at gitter or create an issue in project bug tracker."  Doesn't look to me like you're asking in the right place to really get help.

Comment: I saw the program that was for example and there was a code that do my work but the codes were hard and wasn't able to get the code and find it